# PHP replace and looping character

Tags: php, loops, replace

How to replace character and looping character in PHP?

For example I have data input form textarea like this :

```
#CI
23,45,56x8 788,98,554x7 100x100

or 

@CI
23.45.56x8 788.98.554x7 100x100
```

My teacher said choose one of the above data format and replace that to output into something like this:

```
CI,23,8
CI,45,8
CI,56,8
CI,788,7
CI,98,7
CI,554,7
CI,100,100
```

My code

```
<?php 

    $input = 
    "@CI
    23,45,56x8 788,98,554x7 100x100";

    $reg = "/((?:\d+,)*(?:\d+))x(\d+)/";
    $new = preg_match($reg, $input);
    echo $new;


 ?>
```

Comment: How come it's 23,8 and 45,8 and 98,7. Where does the second number comes from?

Comment: 23,8 --> (8 come from x8) 98,7 --> (7 come from x7)

Comment: Does it come from the x8 of 56x8? Or it's supposed to be 23x8?

Comment: yes that from x8, my teacher say data input from textarea and must be replace like output

Answer (score 0):

such regex as you can see at demo link give you good data structure

```
((?:\d+,)*(?:\d+))x(\d+)
```

result

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-8]   `23,45,56`
2.  [9-10]  `8`
MATCH 2
1.  [11-21] `788,98,554`
2.  [22-23] `7`
MATCH 3
1.  [24-27] `100`
2.  [28-31] `100`
```

[demolimk](https://www.regex101.com/r/pJ0uQ1/1)

Comment: Thanks sir, how to use to php? and how about #CI to loops?

Comment: @TomiTeruz Let's you start to write and we correct your mistakes. Because, for me it's not interest, for you it's helpful

Comment: i use the regex but the output is 1 ?

Comment: Preg_match and preg_match_all does not return a matches. Only Boolean

Comment: I must use match function or replace function?